# gulp - how to pipe tasks

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have this task:

```
var path = require('path');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var conf = require('./conf');
var svgSprite = require("gulp-svg-sprites");
var clean = require('gulp-clean');

gulp.task('sprite-make', function () {

  //first task
  gulp.src([path.join(conf.paths.src, '/assets/svg/*.svg'), '!' + path.join(conf.paths.src, '/assets/svg/sprite.svg')])
    .pipe(svgSprite({
      preview: false,
      svgPath: path.join(conf.paths.src, '/assets/svg/sprite.svg'),
      cssFile: ('_sprite.scss')
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/styles')));

  //second task
  gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/styles/svg/**/*'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.src, '/assets/svg')));

  //third task
  gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/styles/svg'), {read: false})
    .pipe(clean());

});
```

What I want is to execute this tasks one after another (create the sprite -> copy it to new destination -> delete the src).

Currently the tasks running async, and if I try to do `pipe(gulp.src(...)` I am getting the following error: `Unhandled stream error in pipe`

Comment: Why don't you straight away create the sprites in the new destination instead of copying them and deleting them.

Comment: I couldn't find where can I do this in the repo description. I need the scss and the sprite.svg be in different folders. Here is a link to the docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-svg-sprites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty well defined in the doc : https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md

> Note: By default, tasks run with maximum concurrency -- e.g. it
>   launches all the tasks at once and waits for nothing. If you want to
>   create a series where tasks run in a particular order, you need to do
>   two things:
>
> give it a hint to tell it when the task is done, and give it a hint
>   that a task depends on completion of another. For these examples,
>   let's presume you have two tasks, "one" and "two" that you
>   specifically want to run in this order:
>
> In task "one" you add a hint to tell it when the task is done. Either
>   take in a callback and call it when you're done or return a promise or
>   stream that the engine should wait to resolve or end respectively.
>
> In task "two" you add a hint telling the engine that it depends on
>   completion of the first task.
>
> So this example would look like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

// takes in a callback so the engine knows when it'll be done
gulp.task('one', function(cb) {
    // do stuff -- async or otherwise
    cb(err); // if err is not null and not undefined, the run will stop, and note that it failed
});

// identifies a dependent task must be complete before this one begins
gulp.task('two', ['one'], function() {
    // task 'one' is done now
});

gulp.task('default', ['one', 'two']);
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but it is requires to create 3 different tasks, is there any way to do it is with piping?

Comment: Yes, define your second task in the callback of the first and so on. But It is not the proper way to do this.